# What are two most important hyper parameters in multiplayer Perceptron?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I know there are different hyperparameters for `mlpclassifier`, however, if I were to choose two most important one, what would they be for a `digit` dataset? 
1- `Number of hidden layers` and 2- `activation functions` or `alpha`?

How can I tell which one is the most important one?

Comment: How about number of neurons in the hidden layers? They'll be pretty crucial.

Comment: @gunes I think so too, but how about `alpha` and `activation functions`? which one of these two are more important?  How can I choose the most crucial one between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to choose in-between but, just to give you some directions, it's better to recall the meaning of these parameters. `alpha` parameter controls the amount of regularization you apply to the network weights. `activation function` is the nonlinearity we use at the end of each neuron, and it might affect the convergence speed, especially when the network gets deeper. So, if you set a deep network, you might suffer from vanishing gradients if you choose sigmoid or a similar activation function; and you can easily cross out that option from your hyper parameter list and try different levels of regularization, by varying `alpha`. But, if you're dealing with shallower networks, it might worth to go in both directions.